# Can image processing produce image sequences to fake this specific 3D style?

Tags: image-processing

This is more a question about what's possible with image processing and what not.

I wonder if it's technically possible to generate fake 3D sprites with sharp pixels by using only pixel information from 4 flat images and manipulate them to set proper object dimensions with different aspects of depth (see last image), so the end result is a fake 3D object that can be rotated precisely to many angles within a given limit.

[image: 4 images]

Comment: This would appear to be what any 3D modelling software can do. Blender, et al.

Comment: Yes, 3D apps do this readily. But most 2D editors to this too. Theres nothing super hard about this.

Comment: Writing a script to render images from a textured model in a 3D view is not image processing. This question if you want is basically if you can skip the whole process of creating a textured 3D model when above results could be achieved directly with image processing. When you talk about Blender - I don't think it has oblique camera view implemented from what I read. Beyond this question - if there exists a workflow to achieve above results with a 3D Software or any other program then I'm interested too, because I didn't find any type of tutorial on how to achieve something like this.

Comment: Also, I doubt that most 2D editors can do this - not at a comfortable level at least without drawing each frame manually. Do somebody know any 3D or 2D programs which officially support this very specific oblique perspective(besides Unity)? So far I didn't found any useful hint when searching the web. My goal is to generate sprites or sprite sheets.

Comment: You may want an *oblique* projection, but your example isn't really one. It has perspective. That aside, I believe most (if not all) 3D editors support at least *axonometric* projection.

Comment: If you wanted an *axonometric* projection you could make some kind of fake "voxel" graphics by stacking *slices* on top of each other. If the slices are rotated around their individual centers it will create a 2.5D effect. Could you be interested in that? Or is it important to you to have the front face flat and to be able to make this using top, left, right and front views?

Comment: What I want is a very specific task. Yeah, I definitely must avoid the creation of a mesh that is based on real voxels with the texture defined by voxels. All horizontal edges must be straight lines, parallel to each other - rest is all "warping/scaling/extending/reduce pixels" to achieve the right perspective and angles.

Comment: OK. Just be clear, I said "voxels". You can get a voxel like result by stacking images on top of each other. But that requires you to have your objects saved as one image per slice. It's pure image processing. Never mind.

Comment: Yes obviously any 3D application can do oblique view after all its just a matrix transform. And last time i checked, Blender could transform the matrix of an object. As can maya, 3DS max, modo and houdini. Anyway this isnt all that difficult to do in a vector editor either. Likewise photoshop can do this as can stuff like imagemagic. Just dont really know where you want to go with this. Anyway why put extra constraints in the problem. My problem is i can implement a 3D application so for me its all the same. Why would i not use a matrix transform on the pixel data? Its less work after all.

Comment: Ok so maybe it owuld be more constructive for you tio tell us what applications can we use?

Comment: Well, Blender is what I'm using now at the first place. Other Software I could work with are 3ds Max or Cinema 4D, I don't have Modo or Houdini. I need to apply oblique/cabinet perspective view and I need the option to set different view angles in precise steps(view angle "0" looks like  3/4 axonometric projection is always looking - only shows top side and front side). I usually render my textured low poly models from Viewer Node with few modifiers for full pixel quality. I recently changed the way how I create the textured models - I will create these 100% with Sprytile in Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question, but regardless of my lack of understanding on what you need, the answer is mostly yes.

> I wonder if it's technically possible to generate fake 3D sprites

Most 2D image manipulation programs have "skew" and "rotate" You can do that on bitmaps even on vector-based programs.

Most of the raster manipulating programs have some kind of perspective deformation on raster images.

> with sharp pixels

Turn off anti aliasing.

> by using only pixel information from 4 flat images and manipulate them to set proper object dimensions with different aspects of depth (see last image)

Yes, but no program will make it on its own, you need to tell it what you need, what do you need as top image, which deformation you need, which perspective.

You could save one macro or use linked textures. That is how most mock-ups work.

> so the end result is a fake 3D object

No. You will not have a fake 3D object, you will have a resulting image that your brain will interpret if done correctly as a 3D object. Cartoonish if you need. But will only be planes deformed and put together to be interpreted as a 3D object.

> that can be rotated precisely to many angles within a given limit.

So... What you need is... an actual 3D object that can be rotated to some specific angles.

Get some 3D programs and assign the textures to the faces. Then define your lens FOV and angle, and render settings.

Some 2D image programs have some 3D capabilities. Illustrator, Corel Draw, Photoshop. Even a modern web browser and CSS3 can do it. Some just use the tools I mentioned first, but some do actual 3D operations considering the point of view.

So the answer is yes.